# Create a list of lists from two maps with values of the common keys

Tags: groovy

There are two different maps. One is bigger than the other. The keys of small map is always a subset of keys of the bigger map. I want to take the values for keys that are common to both maps and create a list of lists using Groovy features. The objective is to achieve it with as little code as possible with Groovy features.

```
Map big = ['FirstName':'first_name', 'LastName':'last_name', 'FullName':'full_name']
Map small = ['FirstName':'John', 'FullName':'John Williams']
```

**println Output**

```
[[first_name, John], [full_name, John Williams]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//works even if the small map is not a subset completely
def result = []
big.keySet().intersect(small.keySet()).each {
    result << [big[it], small[it]]
}
assert [['first_name', 'John'], ['full_name', 'John Williams']] == result
```

***EDIT:*** Added two variations to the solution suggested by *@taiyebur*

```
// VARIATION 2
def result2 = big.subMap(small.keySet()).collect([]) {
    [it.value, small.get(it.key)]
}
assert [['first_name', 'John'], ['full_name', 'John Williams']] == result2

// VARIATION 3
def result3 = small.collect([]) {
    [big[it.key], it.value]
}
assert [['first_name', 'John'], ['full_name', 'John Williams']] == result3
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It gave me more ideas.

Comment: With `collect` this will do the job: `big.keySet().intersect(small.keySet()).collect { [big[it], small[it] }`